# Что это значит? Вот такая ругань в консоле, при работе compass

Tags: ruby, compass

> [18:34:14] `C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.
>   0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/caniuse.rb`:72: warning: circular argumen
>   t reference - browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В старых версиях гема есть проблемный код, обновите compass и предупреждения исчезнут. Если вы работаете с bundler, просто запустите `bundle update`. 
Подробнее можете прочитать [здесь](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1902).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/229521)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, я и указала самое главное - bundle update :)
Не вижу смысла приводить все остальные подробности из этого issue - они касаются сильно внутренних тонкостей гема compass

Comment: Коренную причину, тем не менее, указать стоит, даже без подробностей. Потому что `bundle update` может и не сработать. Например, в окружениях, которые не используют Bundler (да, такое бывает). Достаточно формулировки вроде "в старых версиях гема есть проблемный код, обновите гем и предупреждения исчезнут".

Comment: @D-side, спасибо за подробный комментарий, исправила ответ. Про то, что бандлера может не быть, я как-то и не подумала

Comment: Спасибо большое